# mySQL Exclude rows from joined table

Tags: mysql

Been cracking my head for the longest. I have two tables, one consists of the customer summary and the other, inventory they purchased (the inventory purchased is each on its own row). I want to return the customer information for orders that have a certain sum of quantity AND meet certain criteria. I thought I had it, but guess not.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
SELECT a.customerTableStuff, SUM(b.quantity) 
FROM order_sum a, order_inv b 
WHERE a.ordernum = b.ordernum AND status = 2 
HAVING quantity <= 2 OR (quantity = 2 AND b.Code NOT LIKE 'C1%')
ORDER BY a.ordernum DESC
```

The Sum seems to work, however, the Code NOT Like is the issue. If another product Code in the row is different then that makes the select true...
I've tried Join as well and get the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you want to be grouping on a.customerTableStuff.  Also, the HAVING is applied AFTER the result is built based on other filters.  A scaled down example would help.

Comment: Im guessing you need to give that SUM an alias otherwise your HAVING is a WHERE so it filters rows not groups. `SUM(b.quantity)  as quantity..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your query.  I think you intend something like:

```
SELECT a.customerTableStuff, SUM(b.quantity) as sumquantity
FROM order_sum a JOIN
     order_inv b 
     ON a.ordernum = b.ordernum AND status = 2 
GROUP BY a.customerTableStuff
HAVING sumquantity < 2 OR
       sum(case when b.code not like 'C1%' then b.quantity else 0 end) = 2
ORDER BY a.ordernum DESC;
```

Comments:

- Use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- You need a `GROUP BY`.
- Your `HAVING` clause is redundant.  The second condition is not necessary.  I'm guessing that you want `< 2` for the first condition.
- Be careful about using unqualified column aliases in the query.  Defining aliases that are the same as column names (`quantity` in your query) can lead to unexpected results.
- I have no idea what `b.code` is supposed to be doing in the `having` clause.  I made a guess.

Comment: I think you need to put `b.Code` into the `SELECT` so you can reference it in `HAVING`.

Comment: @Barmar . . . Good observation.  I wonder what that logic means.  I modified the query and added a note.

Answer (score 0):

Made you should try a UNION

```
SELECT a.customerTableStuff, SUM(b.quantity) 
FROM order_sum a, order_inv b 
WHERE a.ordernum = b.ordernum AND status = 2 
HAVING quantity <= 2
ORDER BY a.ordernum DESC
UNION
SELECT a.customerTableStuff, SUM(b.quantity) 
FROM order_sum a, order_inv b 
WHERE a.ordernum = b.ordernum AND status = 2 
AND b.Code NOT LIKE 'C1%'
HAVING quantity = 2
ORDER BY a.ordernum DESC
```

Comment: Oddly enough, neither worked. Gordon's query gave me the same results I have been getting and the Union gave too many errors. Let me try a different explanation.

Comment: Sorry, got timed out with my response...Oddly enough, neither worked. Gordon's query gave me the same results I have been getting and the Union gave too many errors. Let me try a different explanation.

I have 2 tables as follows:

CustomerTable
 Name OrderID
 John 123456
 David 654321


OrderSummaryTable
 OrderID  ProdCode Qty
 12345  C1002  1
 12345  B1003  1
 54321  B1003  1
 54321  B1003  1

The only result should be 54321 since it has qty under 2 and no prodCode with C1%

Hope this makes more sense

Thanks!

Comment: Oddly enough, neither worked. Gordon's query gave me the same results I have been getting and the Union gave too many errors. Let me try a different explanation.

I have 2 tables as follows:

<code>
CustomerTable
 Name OrderID
 John 123456
 David 654321


OrderSummaryTable
 OrderID  ProdCode Qty
 12345  C1002  1
 12345  B1003  1
 54321  B1003  1
 54321  B1003  1
</code>

The only result should be 54321 since it has qty under 2 and no prodCode with C1%

Hope this makes more sense

Thanks!